# Can't get rid of markdown extension I didn't install

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

I've started redacting markdown files inside VSCode (currently VS Codium, but I face the same issue in VSCode as well).
What bothers me is that I see an odd preview with Chinese hieroglyphs everywhere:
[image]
I have no markdown extension installed (as seen on the left side of the screenshot).
I tried to search for it, found [extension's repo](https://github.com/nicejade/markdown-online-editor) and looked for any similarly named files at `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode-oss\extensions`, but to no avail.
Is there a way to find any markdown-related settings or somehow force the app to use a standard markdown editor or another extension?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't get rid of build in extensions, you can disable them

Comment: that is not from the build in Markdown extension, disable all instaleld and try again

Comment: @rioV8 thank you, decided to pinpoint it by disabling extensions one by one. Turns out, that the Office Viewer extension is causing it. However, it still doesn't change my question - can I override settings what markdown editor should be used? Or removing extensions causing issues is my only solution?

Comment: there is no special Markdown editor, you edit a text file and use a Markdown Viewer that translates Markdown to HTML in a Webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great comment by **rioV8** decided to just go through it manually.
Turns out, that the "Office Viewer" extension is causing it.
While I wanted to find a  way to change it without deleting the extension, technically the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the instructions for Office Viewer

> If you want to use the original vscode editor, insert this in your
> settings.json.
>
> {
> "workbench.editorAssociations": {
> "*.md": "default"
> } }